# Slide left using Object animator android

Tags: android, animation, translate-animation

I want to make view visible with translate animation where it looks like the view is appearing from bottom of another view. Also I am giving Bounce interpolator. But with Translate animation I am facing problems when I hide the view using trnaslate animation and again make it visible with translate animation on click is not working. I searched a lot and many have told to use Object animators or animate() .

This is my translate animation to make visible :

```
fromX = 1.0f
toX = 0.0f
fromY = 0.0f
toY = 0.0f



Animation animation = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, fromX,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, toX, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
            fromY, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, toY);
    animation.setDuration(duration);
    animation.setFillAfter(true);
    animation.setInterpolator(interpolator);
```

To hide :

```
fromX = 0.0f
 toX = 2.0f
 fromY = 0.0f
 toY = 0.0f
```

How can I write this animation using ObjectAnimator or how can I achive the same without using Translateanimation.

Comment: is your requirement similar to Bottom Sheet like animation

Comment: @satuser It is similar to circular menu. Where on click of menu 4 buttons will be shown with animation in arc. And again on click of menu 4 buttons will be hidden.